# Function to use indexes in a matrix

Tags: python, matrix

I am trying to create a function which takes two inputs. One input is the matrix (n*m), and the second is *K*. K is a integer value. The distance between the cells `A[3][2]` and `A[1][4]` is `|1-3| + |4-2| = 4`. The expected output from the function is the count of cells with cell distance greater than *K*.

*Cell* here is each entry in the given matrix A. For example, A[0][0] is a cell and it has an entry value of 1 in the matrix.

I have created a function like this:

```
A = [[1, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0]]

def findw(K, matrix):
    m_c = matrix.copy()
    result = 0
    for i, j in zip(range(len(matrix)), range(len(m_c))):
        for k, l in zip(range(len(matrix[i])), range(len(m_c[j]))):
            D = abs(i - l) + abs(j - k)
            print(i, k)
            print(j, l)
            print(D)
            
            if D > K:
                result += 1
    return result

findw(1, A)
```

The output I got from the above function for the given matrix A with K = 1 is 9. But I am expecting 3. From the output I also realized that for both the matrices my function is always taking same value, for example `(0,0)` or `(1,0)`, etc. See the print output below.

```
findw(1, A)
0 0
0 0
0
0 1
0 1
2
0 2
0 2
4
1 0
1 0
2
1 1
1 1
0
1 2
1 2
2
2 0
2 0
4
2 1
2 1
2
2 2
2 2
0
3 0
3 0
6
3 1
3 1
4
3 2
3 2
2
Out[120]: 9
```

It looks like my function is not iterating for cells where the indexes for both matrices are different. For example, `matrix[0][0]` and `m_c[0][1]`.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: that was a typo. I have corrected it now. it is actually A[3][2] and A[1][4].

Comment: How is the matrix itself (rather than just its dimensions) even relevant for the problem? Doing brute-force search rather than a bit of arithmetic involving `m,n,k` seems fundamentally inefficient. As a possible strategy, it is easy enough to get a total count of the number of pairs of cells. Subtract from that the count of all pairs of cells which are *within* the threshold distance.

Comment: Consider the matrix is a farm land where we want to install wind trubines. cell value with '1' represent birds habitats and we dont want to implement wind turbines closer to bird habitat. how much far way is defined by 'K'. May i check on how can get total distinct pairs from both matrices?

Comment: So you are trying to find pairs of cell *both of which have value 1* whose distance exceeds the threshold? That is a condition which is missing from your problem description as well as your code (you never test the value at the matrix).

Comment: @mkpisk why do you aspect 3 with K=1? if you want to compute the distance of A[2][0]  and A[i][j] you get abs(2-i)+ j, and solve (by hand) the inequality for the counter  abs(2-i)+ j > 1... but for this special case you get more then 3 solutions... so are you sure about that? ...your first zip give you only diagonal element

Comment: @cards it will 3 because in the matrix there are only 3 cells whose distance from the cell (=1) is greater than the threshold value K (=1).

Comment: @JohnColeman, yes. I am trying find those cells which are far way from the cell (=1) and satisfying the distance condition of K=1. In my example it should give the output 3, and the cells for this '3' is (0,2), (1,1) and (2,0).

Comment: @mkpisk It is not obvious to those reading your question that by "cell" you mean a matrix entry which is equal to 1. When writing a question, keep in mind that those reading it don't already know the context. Please edit your question to clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working under the assumption that it is only the positions which have the value `1` that you care about, you could first enumerate those indices and then loop over the pairs of such things. [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) is a natural tool to use here:

```
from itertools import product, combinations

def D(p,q):
    i,j = p
    k,l = q
    return abs(i-k) + abs(j-l)

def findw(k,matrix):
    m = len(matrix)
    n = len(matrix[0])
    result = 0
    indices = [(i,j) for i,j in product(range(m),range(n)) if matrix[i][j] == 1]
    for p,q in combinations(indices,2):
        d = D(p,q)
        if d > k:
            print(p,q,d)
            result += 1
    return result

#test:

A = [[1, 0, 0], 
     [0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 1],
     [0, 1, 0]]

print(findw(1, A))
```

Output:

```
(0, 0) (2, 2) 4
(0, 0) (3, 1) 4
(2, 2) (3, 1) 2
3
```

Comment: is there a way that I give a condition for cell (=1) in combinations instead of defining at 'indices'?

Comment: @mkpisk You could remove the `if` part of the comprehension defining `indices` and then test for whatever condition you want to test for in the loop over the combinations.